# Half of 0xFF characters skipped in stream

Tags: c#, uwp, byte, outputstream, writer

Hi I'm trying to write a byte array containing 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF to an output stream but half of the 0xFF characters are missing at the receiving end.
I know this must be some encoding issue but I cant figure it out. 
this is a simplified code with the same behavior:

```
public async void test()
{
    DataWriter writer;
    using (writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream))
    {
        byte[] data = { 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x02 };
        writer.WriteBytes(data);
        try
        {
            await writer.StoreAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this the client side only receives 0x01 0xFF 0x02
Hope someone can help me with this!
Thanks!

Comment: what is datawriter?

Comment: DataWriter is windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datawriter

Comment: SOLVED Sorry people, the problem turned out to be on the receiving side.